# Is there any modify feature functions like rotate,resize and drag for vector layer in OpenLayers 3 or 4?

Tags: openlayers

I am looking for a sample code for rotate and resize vectors in Openlayers 4, but I can not find anything about it. I found this sample code http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/modify-feature.html but its version Openlayers 2.

I've done this so far

```
   var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({source: source});
  map.addInteraction(modify);

  var catch;
  var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

  function addInteractions() {
    catch = new ol.interaction.Snap({source: source});
    map.addInteraction(catch);
  }
```

I can't find a function like this

```
OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.ROTATE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps these stackoverflow answers could be useful for vector feature rotation

[How to rotate feature in openlayer 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173308/5355375)

[How to change the rotation point (Feature) on the map after it is created and added to map?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29649803/5355375)

ol3-rotate-feature is a plugin for OpenLayers 3 that should provide a rotate vector features interaction.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol3-rotate-feature

The [Translate Features](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/translate-features.html) example using `ol.interaction.Translate` demonstrates dragging interaction for vector layers. Check the [api doc](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Translate.html) for more information.